# how to save the state of those items which have been selected in recyler view even after the app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

What I want to do is to show the same selected items on a recycler view even after the activity has been closed and only change items color when I again click on it. For now I have achieved changing the color on click but the state doesn't get saved?

This is my adapter:

```
public class LightsRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<LightsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  //  private List<Integer> mViewColors;
    private List<String> mAnimals;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    LightsRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,  List<String> 
animals) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.mAnimals = animals;

    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, 
false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

     // binds the data to the view and textview in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
      //  int color = mViewColors.get(position);
        String animal = mAnimals.get(position);
      //  holder.myView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAnimals.size();
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
implements View.OnClickListener {
        View myView;
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           // myView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
            myTextView = 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) 
mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    public String getItem(int id) {
        return mAnimals.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener 
itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

And this is my activity:

```
public class DevicesList extends AppCompatActivity implements         
LightsRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener{

    private LightsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter,adapter1;
    TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_list);

        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textGrid);

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with
        ArrayList<Integer> viewColors = new ArrayList<>();
        viewColors.add(Color.BLUE);
        viewColors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        viewColors.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        viewColors.add(Color.RED);
        viewColors.add(Color.BLACK);

        ArrayList<String> Lab1LightsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Lab1LightsList.add("Light 1");
        Lab1LightsList.add("Light 2");
        Lab1LightsList.add("Light 3");
        Lab1LightsList.add("Light 4");
        Lab1LightsList.add("Light 5");

        ArrayList<String> Lab1ACList = new ArrayList<>();
        Lab1ACList.add("AC 1");
        Lab1ACList.add("AC 2");
        Lab1ACList.add("AC 3");
        Lab1ACList.add("AC 4");
        Lab1ACList.add("AC 5");

        ArrayList<String> Lab2LightsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 1");
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 2");
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 3");
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 4");
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 5");
        Lab2LightsList.add("Light 6");

        ArrayList<String> Lab2ACList = new ArrayList<>();
        Lab2ACList.add("AC 1");
        Lab2ACList.add("AC 2");
        Lab2ACList.add("AC 3");
        Lab2ACList.add("AC 4");


        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list1);
        RecyclerView recyclerView1 =findViewById(R.id.list2);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(DevicesList.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(DevicesList.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("labno", 0);

        if(intValue==0) {
            adapter = new LightsRecyclerViewAdapter(this, Lab1LightsList);
            adapter1 = new LightsRecyclerViewAdapter(this, Lab1ACList);
            adapter.setClickListener(this);
            adapter1.setClickListener(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }

        if(intValue==1) {
            adapter = new LightsRecyclerViewAdapter(this, Lab2LightsList);
            adapter1 = new LightsRecyclerViewAdapter(this, Lab2ACList);
            adapter.setClickListener(this);
            adapter1.setClickListener(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + 
            adapter.getItem(position) + " on item position " + position, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    }
}
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create one selected item position list and store it in prefs when an app goes to background or closed. Load that list when launching an app and compare that list in an adapter's `onBindViewHolder's` `position` parameter and marks it selected/unselected based on a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandings about your question, you want to save the state of the selected items even after the app is closed, and then you want to reload it whenever the app is launched again. You need to refer to this link [Android Save Data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

For the above solution, there can be various ways to save state, I am mentioning a few below:

1. Use **SQLite Database** to save the selected items. Then, whenever the app is loaded, fetch all the selected data from the DB and then mark them selected with whatever colour you want on the list.
2. You can also use **Shared Preferences**, to store the selection. And, same as above, you can reload the data when the app is launched.
3. You can also store the data in a specific format, maybe CSV, JSON, XML etc., in a **file** and save it either in Internal Storage or External Storage of the device. And when the app is launched, fetch all the selected values from the file and process accordingly.
4. You can also use a **web server, Firebase Storage, or other cloud storage** services to save the data and then fetch the data on new app launch.

Do note: All these techniques require you to save the state before the app is closed. So it is better to store the states, either on click of the item, or onPause method of the activity.

If you face any problems with these solutions, you can post another comment and I will give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Save these clicked item position in a hashmap in Shareprefence. suppose u close the activity after u coming back the activity just pass the saved list with ur data in adapter and compare the shareprefence list with ur data list if position or data match than make the itemview layout colored.

```
 // save clicked item is a list and save it sharePreference.
 List<Integer> clikedList = new ArrayList<>();
 if (clicked item){
 ClikedList.add(position)
 }
 String value = gson.toJson(list);
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("mylist", 
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Editor e = prefs.edit();
 e.putString("list", value);
 e.commit();
 // for getting cliked position list from SharePreference

 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("mylist", 
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String value = prefs.getString("list", null);

 GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
 Gson gson = gsonb.create();
 MyObject[] list = gson.fromJson(value, MyObject[].class);

 @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
 // suppose clicked position 4 u get from shaved cliked list
 in here u neddd to retreive cliked list position and clored those item

 int select = 4;
 if (select == position) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#214F4B"));
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 holder.tv_title.setText(data.get(position));
}
```